# Issue with InputStreamConstructor

Tags: java, io, inputstreamreader

I tried to collect the data from a socket. For that, I coded :

```
  InputStream i = socket.getInputStream();
  InputStreamReader rawAnswer= InputStreamReader(i);
```

But an error occured ( I use Eclipse as an IDE ) : " The method InputStreamReader(InputStream) is undefined". However, the documentation says that the constructor exists. I then tried to create an InputStreamReader from a FileInputStream and it worked perfectly. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: You need to use `new` to call a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`new`!

```
InputStreamReader rawAnswer= new InputStreamReader(i);  
                          // ^^^
```

Otherwise you are just trying to call a method that unusually has an initial cap.

Another common mistake is to attempt to declare a constructor but add a `void` return type, thus creating a method with an initial cap. (Funnily enough, in byte code constructors do have `void` return types but are called `<init>`.)

Comment: Guess I must be tired... Thanks you !

Comment: @AlainSisyphe It's a common mistake. You should now recognise the problem and when it reoccurs you should now be able to work out how to fix it yourself within a split second.